# Add properties to routes in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to know if it's possible to add a custom property to the routes defined in RouteConfig decorator.

I would like to add whatever a route needs authentication or not:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: LoginComponent,
    authenticate: false,
  },
  {
    path: "/home",
    name: "Home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    authenticate: true
  }
])
```

If this is possible, how do I get the value "authenticate" in the component?

Comment: hmmm! seems like you want to add/use feature of `ui-router` from `angular1` :-)!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that you could leverage the `data` property of the `RouteDefinition` interface:

```
@RouteConfig([
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login",
    component: LoginComponent,
    data: {
      authenticate: false
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/home",
    name: "Home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: {
      authenticate: true
    }
  }
])
```

It's of type `any` so you can put what you want in it (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/router/route_definition.ts#L25):

```
export interface RouteDefinition {
  path?: string;
  aux?: string;
  component?: Type | ComponentDefinition;
  loader?: Function;
  redirectTo?: any[];
  as?: string;
  name?: string;
  data?: any;
  useAsDefault?: boolean;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But how do I get the data object from one of the Components fx. HomeComponent? I can't find it on "Router"?

Comment: Found it! "RouteData" has the magic :) From this article:http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

Comment: Great! Yes, you can inject `RouteData` to get the data associated with the current route...